# NFS error when vagrant up

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox, salt-stack

I am having this error everytime i vagrant up the customer environment:

```
    NFS requires a host-only network to be created.
    Please add a host-only network to the machine (with either DHCP or a
    static IP) for NFS to work.
```

Here is the message when i try to vagrant up. The error message came out right after this:

```
    manager: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    manager: Checking if box 'centos/7' is up to date...
    manager: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    manager: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    manager: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    manager: Adapter 1: nat
    manager: Adapter 2: hostonly
    manager: You are trying to forward to privileged ports (ports <= 1024). Most
    manager: operating systems restrict this to only privileged process (typically
    manager: processes running as an administrative user). This is a warning in case
    manager: the port forwarding doesn't work. If any problems occur, please try a
    manager: port higher than 1024.
    manager: Forwarding ports...
    manager: 2375 (guest) => 172 (host) (adapter 1)
    manager: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    manager: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    manager: Booting VM...
    manager: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    manager: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    manager: SSH username: vagrant
    manager: SSH auth method: private key
    manager: Machine booted and ready!
    manager: Setting hostname...
    manager: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
    manager: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    manager: SSH username: vagrant
    manager: SSH auth method: private key
```

I have done some researchs and seen similar cases, but most of the answer pointed out that there's lacking a config.vm.network in vagrantfile. **Im totally sure that is not the case here**, since i have checked the vagrantfile already, and my colleagues can vagrant up just fine in their PCs.

For now, i have tried to reinstall virtualbox (5.1.30), vagrant (2.0.0), but it does not work. Please help

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html

Comment: If the IP in the Vagrantfile is the same as others, it could be the cause. "Do not choose an IP that overlaps with any other IP space on your system. This can cause the network to not be reachable."

Comment: well, i have tried to delete all other VMs, and vagrant up only single VM:

        vagrant up manager

But it still get that error, so i think IP collision is not the problem here.

Comment: having other VMs shouldn't matter as long as you Vagrant up in the correct folder for that VM. Did it provision on the first vagrant up? If not try using the --provision flag. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/

Comment: yes, i have run the vagrant up in the environment folder. I have tried to vagrant up only 1 machine (they consists of 3), the manager node. I have edited the post to add the messages when trying to vagrant up manager. the error come out right after that.

Comment: This happened here too after I had temporarily disabled a bunch of VirtualBox network interfaces for some other issue I had with a non-related problem. I re-enabled the interfaces but the NFS mount kept failing; your answer seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my question:

basically something in my Virtualbox got screwed up and the host only network interface was being created but somehow lost registration with virtualbox. Here are the things that i did:

- Check all the vagrant plugin that is needed (often required in vagrantfile)
- Delete all the boxes that created by vagrant.
- Delete all the NAT and host-only network card and recreate them.
- Change the Ipv4 address of host-only network to the correct one of the box you want to create (depend on what you config in the vagrantfile). I also have to disable the DHCP server in this case.

Hope this can help some of the similar cases i saw in the internet. This is a known issue for vagrant and virtualbox.